# Не отображается строка при чтении с файла

Tags: c

Не работает код (на Си) как требует задача *(Написать программу, которая считывает текст из файла (несколько предложений) и выводит его на экран. После каждого предложения печатается количество символов в нем)*
Вот кусок моего кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define max 150

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    FILE * fp;
    char words[max];
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\textt.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("\n\tОшибка открытия файла\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(words, max, fp) != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s", words);
        printf("Количество слов в рядке: %d\n", strlen(words));
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `textt.txt` точно так файл называется?

Comment: да, и кодировка верная, путь к файлу тоже.

Comment: а что у Вас выводит консоль что-то не то?

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Как минимум, `strlen` возвращает длину строки, а не количество слов в "рядке"...

Comment: проблема в том, что сам текст (Допустим: Привет как дела) оно выводит, но в printf("Количество слов в рядке: %d\n", strlen(words)); выводятся только подсчитанные символы (и то, неверно :( ), а вместо строки, прописанной в функции "-:"

Comment: у меня код выводит правильно все с учетом перевода каретки `LF` 0x0A (linux)
`1111 qq
Количество слов в рядке: 8` и `222 qq
Количество слов в рядке: 7` только не слов а символов

Comment: может ли это быть проблема в самой системе? я не очень разбираюсь в этом вопросе, ошибок вроде бы нет, но программа не работает как надо, для меня это удивительно :D

Comment: может, а как и в чем Вы компилируете?

Comment: компилирую в  среде Dev-C++, у меня уже раньше бывало такое, что программа "чинилась" спустя время, в этом случае не работает

Comment: а компилятор какой там настроен ? я использовал **gcc version 11.3.0** кстати проверьте шрифт в консоли может там кириллицы нет

Comment: у меня tdm-gcc version 4.9.2, извините,я не совсем понял, как именно проверить шрифт. при компиляции программы -> свойства?

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");` в винде может не работать. проверьте возвращаемое значение. Если вернулось `NULL`, то это было ошибка. попробуйте вместо этого `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF-8");` или как там ещё там...